# Categories on help command for Discord bot

Tags: python, discord

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezv5m.png]

As you can see, the category says "No category".
How can I change the category for a command?

My code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    """Pong"""
    await bot.say(":ping_pong: Pong!")
    print ("user has pinged")
```

Comment: I actually forgot how to do this (because I have a bad habit of caring more about functionality than organization), but if you visit the Discord API server, or Egg And Sebi's Bot Tutorial server, they can definitely help you out.

It is also likely that the information you are looking for can be found in the discord.py API: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Please don't repost questions in the future, edit your existing question to make it clear. When a question is marked as unclear, it is actually placed on hold. After you edit your unclear question, reviewers have the option to vote to reopen your post.

Comment: Can you give me Egg And Sebi's Bot Tutorial server?

Comment: Categories are separated by "cogs", use the add_cog function to create a cog class.

Comment: What i need to type after add_cog my category name or another thing?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want the complexity of adding Cogs for a simple bot, you can rewrite the "No Category" string by modifying the HelpCommand: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.DefaultHelpCommand.no_category

For example:

```
...
from discord.ext import commands
...

# Change only the no_category default string
help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(
    no_category = 'Commands'
)

# Create the bot and pass it the modified help_command
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or('?'),
    description = description,
    help_command = help_command
)
```

The result should look like:

```
This is the bot description

​Commands:
  something Do something
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, for any new people that come here, the syntax for creating cogs has been changed. Now your class has to inherit from `commands.Cog`, `pass_context` has been depreciated, and you have to await the `add_cog` or `load_extension` method. So if you want to have a cog in the same file of the bot then you need to use the following format:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
   """Cog description"""

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        """Command description"""
        await ctx.send("Pong!")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog())

bot.run('token')
```

I recommend not doing this and having separate files for each cog, if you want a example on that, check out:

- [The documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs)
- [An Example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be)

Comment: The example is no longer accurate as one needs to await `add_cog`/`load_extension` now. This can be fixed by putting it inside the `on_ready` method.

Comment: @Natan You can suggest an edit to the answer by using the Edit button

Comment: I could, but "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later."

Comment: @Natan Okay I edited it, let me know if it's correct now :)

Comment: I was able to suggest an edit now. But your solution got closer to working :)

Answer (score 3):

Help message categories are separated by cogs.

You can add cogs by using [`bot.add_cog(cog)`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/e2de93e2a65960c9c83e8a2fe53d18c4f9600196/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L622).

```
class SomeCategory:
    """Category documentations"""

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        """Pong"""
        await bot.say(":ping_pong: Pong!")
        print ("user has pinged")

bot.add_cog(SomeCategory())
```

Comment: Isn't this changing the name of the class, which the category defaults to? I think that many asking this question are looking for a way to directly change the category that commands are listed under. For example, is it possible to have commands from different cogs (classes) listed under the same category?