# How to add categories to commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the discord.py rewrite and I am experimenting with the help command, Right now when I do !help it will just give me every command i want to be able to split the commands up into different categories so that when I do !help it will show the different categories of commands not just the commands
Here is some code

```
@client.command(name='test' , brief='This is the brief description', description='This is the full description')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

This is what !help looks like right now:

```
No Category:
    test     This is the brief description

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

I assume i am going to have to add another thing onto the @client.command() Line but i am not sure what i need to add to sort it into categories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Categories on help command for Discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006738/categories-on-help-command-for-discord-bot)

Answer (score 1):

To create categories, you'd have to use [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs). Here's a quick example of a cog (or category):

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

class My_Cog(commands.Cog, name='Your Cog Name'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='test' , brief='This is the brief description', description='This is the full description')
    async def test(ctx):
        await ctx.send('test')

bot.add_cog(My_Cog(bot))
bot.run(token)
```

In a cog, there are a few modifications compared to the usual:

- To exploit events, you have to use the `@commands.Cog.listener()` decorator.
- To create commands, you have to use the `@commands.command()` decorator.
- Every `bot` or `client` reference becomes `self.bot` (or whatever you defined it to).

You can also separate cogs into different files, which is not the case in the example I gave. To separate it into different files, you can create a `cogs` folder with all your cogs and add this function at the end of every file:

```py
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(My_Cog(bot))
```

Finally, you can add this to your main file:

```py
from os import listdir

for file in listdir('cogs/'):
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]})
```